# Submit button with two actions

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form that modifies meta content of table 'wp_postmeta'.  I'm trying to figure out a way to add the form results to another table (transactions).

I have the php setup and it works if I remove the "id" value from the submit input section.  With ID included, the form modifies wp_postmeta but no data is sent to "transactions" table.  Without ID included, the opposite.  Any suggestions?

**FORM Submit button:**

```
<div class='inventory-management-form-item-holders inventory-management-submit-holder'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="im-submit">
</div>
```

**"im-submit" js SECTION:**

```
// submit form
jQuery("#im-submit").click(function(){
    // Change thw loading Gif url 
    jQuery('#the-results-holder').html("<img src='/wp-content/plugins/mcs-inventory-management/assets/images/loading_icon.gif' />");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {'im-product-id': theProductId, 'status-quantity': jQuery('#status-quantity').val(), 'status-action': jQuery('#im-action-box').val(), 'status-location': jQuery('#status-location').val(), 'status-move-location': jQuery('#status-move-location').val()},
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/inventory-management-process/",
        processData: true,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#the-results-holder').html(""); 
            jQuery('#status-stock').val(data.stock);
            jQuery('#status-res').val(data.res);
            jQuery('#status-prepro').val(data.prepro);
            jQuery('#status-clean').val(data.clean);
            jQuery('#status-quantity').val("0");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            jQuery('#the-results-holder').html(""); 
            jQuery('#the-results-holder-error').html("There has been an error!"); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**PHP That uses INSERT Query for "transaction" table**

```
<form name='inventory-management' id='inventory-management-form' method="POST" action='<?php $transaction ?>'>


<?php
$product= $_POST['part-number'];
$action= $_POST['status-action'];
$from_location= $_POST['status-location'];
$to_location= $_POST['status-move-location'];
$qty= $_POST['status-quantity'];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $transaction = "INSERT INTO transactions (id,product,action,from_location,to_location,qty) VALUES ('','$product','$action','$from_location','$to_location','$qty')";
 $result = mysql_query($transaction);
}
?>
```

Comment: If you remove the ID the form submits instead of the jQuery ajax because of `jQuery("#im-submit")` - add the update to the /inventory-management-process/ php - what does action='<?php $transaction ?>'> do? Should that not be action='<?php echo $transaction; ?>'>

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to update by id on one table, and do an insert on another?  Why don't you just use two separate statements running one after another?

Comment: Correct, without the ID, the jQuery doesn't run.  Yes, I am trying to update and insert. Which statement would I duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works if you remove the "id" value from the submit input section because the form is submitted by the browser and not by your js code and then the `submit` value is in the `$_POST`.

to make your jQuery code works you need to add the `submit` value to the post, something like this:

```
    // submit form
jQuery("#im-submit").click(function() {
    // Change thw loading Gif url 
    jQuery('#the-results-holder').html("<img src='/wp-content/plugins/mcs-inventory-management/assets/images/loading_icon.gif' />");

    var ajax_config = {
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'submit': 'submit',  
            'im-product-id': theProductId, 
            'status-quantity': jQuery('#status-quantity').val(), 
            'status-action': jQuery('#im-action-box').val(), 
            'status-location': jQuery('#status-location').val(), 
            'status-move-location': jQuery('#status-move-location').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/inventory-management-process/",
        processData: true,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#the-results-holder').html("");
            jQuery('#status-stock').val(data.stock);
            jQuery('#status-res').val(data.res);
            jQuery('#status-prepro').val(data.prepro);
            jQuery('#status-clean').val(data.clean);
            jQuery('#status-quantity').val("0");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            jQuery('#the-results-holder').html("");
            jQuery('#the-results-holder-error').html("There has been an error!");
        }
    };
    jQuery.ajax(ajax_config);//jajax # 1

    //change the url
    ajax_config.url = jQuery('#inventory-management-form').attr("action");

    jQuery.ajax(ajax_config);//jajax # 2

    return false;
});
```

**EDIT:**

i think you are posting to two different locations, that's why without the ID, it adds the form results to transactions table and with the ID, it updates the wp_postmeta table. you should try using the ID, and in the jQuery code, make 2 ajax call, one just like you have and another changing the url to the form action value.

```
'url': jQuery('#inventory-management-form').attr("action")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I added the   'submit': 'submit',   and tried it with and without the  id='im-submit'  Neither worked.  I assume I leave the   jQuery("#im-submit").click(function(){   as is?

Comment: if you want to use jQuery, don't remove the ID form the html, make the change i suggested, and try it.

Comment: Also tried 'submit': jQuery('#im-submit').val(), ... no luck with that either.

Comment: Are you using a debug toolbar like `Firebug`? Can you check where you are submitting the form with and without the ID in the html submit button? are the same location? in the code you posted you have `action='<?php $transaction ?>'`, should that not be `action='<?php echo $transaction; ?>'>` as @mplungjan suggested? is `url: "/inventory-management-process/",` the correct url where the submit should be sent?

Comment: With the id:  it updates the wp_postmeta table
Without the id: it adds the form results to transactions table

Not sure it needs the echo because the query runs when id is excluded from the submit.  url is correct

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 statements run off one button?

Comment: I added the 'url':... as you mentioned after the 'status-move-location':... line. With ID still in there, makes the UPDATE but not the INSERT.  Where in Firebug can I check "where" they are submitting?

Comment: check my answer again, i edited it, check the first code

Comment: Yee Haa!  That worked.  However, the ERROR message is showing even though the transaction table shows the addition and the inventory is moved correctly.  I guess I could change the error message to "Transaction Completed" ...haha

Comment: this is working on my end, however, another user is not having success.  I logged in with their credentials and it works fine.  We are both using Chrome (and it works with FireFox).  He is in another town on a PC.  I am using a Mac.  Any idea why his stuff isn't showing up?  His is not making changes to either table where I was able to do one or the other.